# build jar with maven, contain a list of spring service and add it to war

Tags: spring, maven, service, jar

I am using **Spring** with **Maven** and **Tomcat**. I have a Spring MVC application which has a public front-end WAR,and a shared services JAR. My JAR contain list of service annotated by spring annotation `@Service` and i configure my Application context inside this jar like bellow.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
     xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"  
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.bergit.jpa" />




    <!-- Import file which containt parameter need it to configure the DB and hibernate -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="META-INF/config/jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- Database connection settings -->

    <bean id="dataSource-seconde"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!--   Configuration for Hibernate/JPA  -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory-seconde"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource-seconde" /> -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testspring-jpa-seconde" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
           <bean  class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql"          value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl"      value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.dialect}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pum"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager-seconde"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory-seconde" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource-seconde" />
    </bean>                                    
</beans>
```

and this is my class java is writed like bellow:

```
@Service("userJARService")
public class UserJARServiceImpl implements UserJARService {...}
```

i tested my Jar using Junit and it's ok.
now i add this jar into my war (add inside the pom file of war).
i write my class of controller for my first view where i inject my first service which i want to use it inside this conctroller `UserJARService` like bellow:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(AccessClassToWebService.CONTROLLER_BASE_PATH)
public class AccessClassToWebService {
    @Autowired
    UserJARService userJARService;
}
```

now i add this jar dependency inside the pom of my war. But i get the error bellow

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.bergit.jpa.service.UserJARService ....**

Comment: Where do you have deployed your war Tomcat, Wildfly, Weblogic?

Comment: i deploy my war into tomcat

Comment: Your `base-package` is wrong. It is a package not a pattern or class reference... `com.bergit.jpa.service` and `com.bergit.jpa.repository` or only `com.bergit.jpa` is enough. Also you should be programming to interfaces `UserJARService` instead of the actual implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum: yes i changed like this but i have same error **No matching bean of type [com.bergit.jpa.service.UserJARService]**

Comment: You have changed what?

Comment: @M.Deinum: i updated my question you can look what i have. i update the **base-package** and the code java of class `AccessClassToWebService`